# How do I get comments from tiktok Videos from the official API?

Tags: tiktok, tiktok-api

I want to fetch, display and post comments to a tiktok video, I am getting the video ID and comments count but can't get the actual comments, Is that even possible with the official API ?

I have read the documentation and they say it is possible through the research API, but for that I would need the **research client**, and as written in the documentation it will be given once my app is approved, now My app is approved but the **research client** link says : You do not have any research clients, and their is no option to create it myself, tell me how do I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

To use TikTok research API you need to qualify as a researcher. Here are the criteria:

- Have demonstrable academic experience and expertise in the research
  area specified in the application
- Have no conflicts of interest with respect to using the services
- Be employed by a US non-profit academic institution
- Be able to provide a clearly defined research proposal
- Be committed to only using data for non-commercial purposes

https://developers.tiktok.com/products/research-api/

If you qualify, it should be able to read the comments using the query video comments: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/research-api-specs-query-video-comments/

Other than that, I don't think it's possible to get comments using the official API.